# DrawItem() not get called in CListCtrl

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I have created CListCtrl using LVS_REPORT and LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED style. But DrawItem() and MeasureItem() not get called.

```
CAlarmList *pAlrmList;
pAlrmList= new CAlarmList;  //CAlarmList derived from CLIstCtrl
    pAlrmList->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE  | WS_VSCROLL| LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED| LVS_REPORT | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT , CRect(0,0,600,400), this, ID_ALARMLIST);



 void CAlarmList::MeasureItem(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpMeasureItemStruct) 
    {   
        lpMeasureItemStruct->itemHeight = 22; 
    }

    void CAlarmList::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDIS)
    {
        int iListItem = lpDIS->itemID;  
    }

    virtual void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct);
    virtual void MeasureItem(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpMeasureItemStruct);
```

Comment: There is no check for the return code of Create... Is it really created? Did you really add members to it?

Comment: I added column headers. It is created and have columns also.I get data from my CPtrList and i will add to control  in DrawItem(). I dont know how the DrawItem() get called automatically.Even i want to change the height of the row, so i added MeasureItem(),but that one also not get added.

Comment: DrawItem and MeasureItem are called when needed. You need to add rows (InsertItem)...